When did Endeavor learn how to fly?
There was a chapter in the anime when Endeavor fought a Nomu, he was seeing like flying, another hero asked him if he could fly,and he said he could only float (not fly). But now in season 7th of the anime, we see him flying.
When did Endeavor learn how to fly?
